# Underscorejs when used with requirejs returning undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, underscore.js

I am using requirejs and in one of my files underscore is a dependency. The below is the piece of code to include underscore.

```
define(["lib/underscore"], function(_) {
    // Here _ is undefined
});
```

With a little research I figured out that underscore is adding it to global namespace. Underscore returns undefined and that is why _ is becoming undefined. If I use the following way _ is valid.

```
define(["lib/underscore"], function() {
    // Here _ is defined
};
```

In the above code I am not overwriting the _ that is added to global name space.

In my exploration to find out why underscore is not returning the _ I found this following piece of code in underscore.js

```
// AMD registration happens at the end for compatibility with AMD loaders
  // that may not enforce next-turn semantics on modules. Even though general
  // practice for AMD registration is to be anonymous, underscore registers
  // as a named module because, like jQuery, it is a base library that is
  // popular enough to be bundled in a third party lib, but not be part of
  // an AMD load request. Those cases could generate an error when an
  // anonymous define() is called outside of a loader request.
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define('underscore', [], function() {
      return _;
    });
  }
```

It means when underscore is loaded through requirejs it should return _ instead of undefined. It is not happening to me. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The underscore snippet you provided above only runs when `define` exists. You're probably loading underscore on the page before RequireJS. Also, underscore is registering itself as a named module. Named modules are normally required using that name, instead of a path.

You can either:

- If you need underscore as a regular global, load underscore *after* you load RequireJS on the page. That way, it declares itself as a global as well as a named module. You can then require underscore using its name rather than a path like: `define(['underscore'], function(_){...});`
- Don't require underscore and Continue using the global `_`. but that defeats the purpose of you having RequireJS in the first place.

Comment: 1. define exists when underscore is called and I am loading RequireJS before underscore.
2. The path was also right I was able to debug to the code I have specified above.

Comment: @kishore Underscore registers itself as *a named module*. That means it *should be referred to by name, not by path*. The first bullet point in my answer should resolve that issue.

Comment: so I have to define a path in requirejs config right

Comment: @kishore No, just the name "underscore" instead of path.